# 00905.0000-"missing statement in oracle"

Tags: oracle

```
select fpl_experience,
  (trunc(months_between(sysdate,a.FPL_START_DATE))/12)/count(b.id_associate) as   fpl_experience_percentage 
from tb_associate_fpl_details a 
join tb_allocation_details b on a.id_associate= b.id_associate 
(case fpl_experience 
  when fpl_experience_percentage < 0.5 then 'Less than 6 months' 
  when fpl_experience_percentage>0.5 and fpl_experience_percentage<2 then 'Greater than 6M and less than 2Y')
   when fpl_experience_percentage>2 and fpl_experience_percentage<3 then 'between 2 and 3 years') ELSE 
  'greater than 3 years' end) as fpl_experience 
 group by a.fpl_start_date having b.asso_region='ON';
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query has several errors:

- your CASE expression belongs in the SELECT part
- `case fpl_experience when fpl_experience_percentage < 0.5` doesn't make sense - get rid of the `fpl_experience`
- you have stray `)` at several places in your CASE

Comment: as fpl_experience_percentage from 
(select (case when fpl_experience_percentage < 0.5 then 'Less than 6 months' 
  when fpl_experience_percentage>0.5 and fpl_experience_percentage<2 then 'Greater than 6M and less than 2Y'
   when fpl_experience_percentage>2 and fpl_experience_percentage<3 then 'between 2 and 3 years' ELSE 
  'greater than 3 years' end)) as fpl_experience from tb_associate_fpl_details a 
join tb_allocation_details b on a.id_associate= b.id_associate 
 group by a.fpl_start_date having b.asso_region='ON';

Comment: @user3683603 Please don't dump code in comments. If you have additional information, edit your question instead. If you have a different question, ask a different question on SO.